# Starting a project-specific web service automatically when running a VI

Tags: web-services, service, configuration, labview, autostart

I have a project which has a Web Resource set up, as shown in the image below:

[image: Project tree snapshot]

Currently, if I want `TemperatureService` to accept connections, I need to right click it and then choose <kbd>Start</kbd>. This is somewhat inconvenient, but more importantly, requires an additional step from the operator of these tools,  which might lead to undesired human error due to forgetfulness, unawareness etc.

For this reason, I would like to have the ability to start `TemperatureService` automatically when running a certain VI in this project. So far I have found several resources/tutorials <sup>[1](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/7747/en/), [2](http://chrislarson.me/blog/labview-web-services-create-web-resource.html), [3](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/6816DE13DCE0601986256C02007DEAA5)</sup>, but all I could gather was how to auto-start the *admin interface* of the web service, which is done by adding the following blocks to the VI (mainly [Open Application Reference](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361M-01/glang/open_application_reference/)):

[image: VIs needed to autostart the "global" service]

... which didn't start the service. I also tried setting the `Property Node`'s property to `Server:TCP Listener Active`, but this didn't have the desired effect either.

To summarize: **how can I automatically start a specific web service when running a VI?**

I am working with LabVIEW 2015 running on a 64-bit Win 7.

Comment: Is this web service supposed to be self-contained or is it part of a larger application? And are you intending to deploy it on a computer without LabVIEW (using the Application Builder) or is it only going to run inside the development environment?

Comment: @nekomatic This is supposed to be a self-contained RESTful service that only runs on the development environment as part of running the VI. To avoid the XY-problem issue, the grand plan here is being able to expose some value that is being measured in LabVIEW to MATLAB (running on the same or on another computer on the same LAN).

Comment: OK, according to http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361M-01/lvconcepts/ws_distributing/ once you have started the service from the project explorer it should stay running until you unpublish it again, even through a system restart, so is there a problem with starting it and leaving it started? Alternatively you could achieve your objective by having your VI run its own TCP/IP server (not hard, see LabVIEW examples) as there seems to be support for TCP/IP comms in MATLAB. Or if you have the Application Builder you could deploy your VI and service in a built application.

Comment: The links in your post are all rather out of date btw (the first one even admits it) - see your LabVIEW 2015 help for current info.

Comment: "_is there a problem with starting it and leaving it started?_" The problem is that I don't want to start it _manually_. Publishing and creating a standalone app is also something you must do manually, which only leaves me with the option of running a TCP/IP server of my own... I guess there's no choice....

Comment: But my point is, if you only want to run it on the same machine where you've developed it, why not just start it running manually now and (according to the NI help doc) it will keep running forever until you stop it, or presumably uninstall LabVIEW? If you need someone else to install and run it on a different machine in future then I see your point (and the answer is to build it with an installer) but if it's just this machine then where's the issue? If I've misunderstood please clarify.

Comment: @nekomatic do you mean to tell me that if I start the service, then close LabVIEW and/or reset the computer, the service would automatically be running the next time I open LabVIEW? I find this hard to believe. Nevertheless, I will give it a try....

Comment: That's my reading of the help doc I linked to, though it's not something I've tried myself. You need to check the application web server is enabled: http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361M-01/lvconcepts/ws_web_server/ . Let me know if it works and if so I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: So I just tried starting the service then closing the project (not even LabVIEW) and reopening the project to see if it still work - the answer is **no** (so no point in testing the reopening LabVIEW or a full reset). The application web server is exactly what is being enabled by the block combination on the bottom of my question.. This is not the same as enabling the REST server _of the project_ unfortunately... I appreciate your attempts to help...

Comment: See http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361N-01/lvprop/app_web_srvsrv_active/ : looks like you need to enable it in LabVIEW Options>Web Server for the setting to persist? Also check you don't have a port number clash: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/5963066F572549BE862576E3006B24A3 ?

Comment: @nekomatic Again, this is exactly what I do **in the question**. The ports are ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following [this tutorial](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361M-01/lvhowto/build_web_service/) on the NI site, I was able to successfully create a persistent web service that continued to run after exiting LabVIEW and after restarting the computer (or at least, the VM in which I run LabVIEW).

As described in the tutorial, if you start the web service by right-clicking it in the project and choosing **Start**, the service runs in a debugging server which terminates when you exit LabVIEW.

However when you choose **Application Web Server > Publish**, the service runs in LabVIEW's application web server and continues to run after exiting LabVIEW and after restarting the computer.

[image: project window showing Publish menu]

Note that the application web server runs on a different port from the debug server; after publishing the service, right-click on a method VI and choose **Show Method URL...** to see the correct address.

[image: Method URL dialogue]

If deployment fails with the error `Target OS for this Web service differs from the Web server configuration`, make sure that the server is [configured for the same runtime](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/90880283B2F833D7862577900073A2A1) (i.e. 32 or 64 bit) as the LabVIEW development environment.

Comment: Thank you - this is useful advice! I would also add that deployment could fail with the error `Target OS for this Web service differs from the Web server configuration.`. To avoid it, one has to make sure that the server is configured for the same runtime (i.e. 32 or 64 bit) as the LabVIEW development environment, as [shown here](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/90880283B2F833D7862577900073A2A1).

Comment: Thanks, I've edited this info into the answer. Glad to hear we fixed it!